# C# get user to create class instance

Tags: c#, object

If one had a class such as 'Painter' and one needed the user to be able to create an instance or instances of this class @ runtime, what's the best way to go about this?

So each time a user clicks a button, we need a new painter object?

Or each time the user enters 'new painter' we need a new painter instance?

Comment: All object instances are created at runtime by calling the type constructor. You need to elaborate a little more your question. Are you trying to let the user type C# code that will be dynamically evaluated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) from a `string` using [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

Once you've got a `Type` object, you can call [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to instantiate it, or call [`Type.GetConstructors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructors.aspx), choose an appropriate constructor and then invoke it.

Two "gotchas" about `Type.GetType`, by the way:

- You have to include the namespace in the type name
- Unless the type is in the currently executing assembly or `mscorlib`, you need to specify the assembly name as well *with version information if it's strongly named*

If you have a reference to the assembly in question, then [`Assembly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) can be a simpler approach - you still need to include the namespace though.

Comment: "version information if it's strongly typed" should have been "version information if it's strongly named"

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the gist of your question is that the class type is unknown prior to the user's input.  Otherwise, if you wanted a new Painter class on each button click, you could simply handle the button click and do "`var newpainter = new Painter();`".

So, assuming you need to dynamically create an instance of an unknown type, you can use reflection to do this at runtime.

```
var newpainter =  Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Painter"), args);
```